# How to connect my database on cpanel to my mobile application?

Tags: database, wordpress, firebase, flutter, cpanel

I am hosting a website on wordpress and wordpress is on a cpanel of a free hosting site. I want some data of my website in my flutter mobile application. So is there any way I can pull some specific data to my mobile app. I have access to mysql database in cpanel but what I lack is how to connect that database to my app.

I thought a way to push data from wordpress to firebase using plugin in wordpress (Integrate Firebase Plugin) but I think having 2 databases with same data in it might be inconvenient and not much cost friendly.

Answer (score 1):

you can start by connecting your mysql database with flutter app by creating a "name".php
for connecting and include this "name".php in other files and function , and in your flutter side you should use the http package in every function you should use the post function , this is the way that I have done and implemented in my project , it is a little bit tricky at start but you should get used to it .
the video that helped me a lot is this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT5WuFRJ2no&ab_channel=SantosEnoque

Comment: if it helped please mark my answer as correct